# UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl in iOS 5 beta missing

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, ios5

In my latest release application, everything looks good on iOS4+, but not on iOS5 Beta.
The only thing that is wrong is that the UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl is not shown on iOS5 devices. It shows an empty UIBarButtonItem with style Plain.

It looks good in IB in XCode 4.1, will test on my work computer as well on the BETA XCode tomorrow.

Does anyone know why this happens, or is this a bug in iOS5 beta?

***EDIT***
The question: If someone else found this too, how can I fix it (the correct way!)?

Comment: You shouldn't ask iOS 5 question here, it's under NDA. There's devforums for that https://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: I know, I am just wondering if I am the only one or if someone else noticed this to and solved it.

Comment: I think it missed earlier. I can't see it in 4.3 already.

Comment: It works in IB for XCode 4.2 BETA and 4.1. Weird.

Comment: [File a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com). Does it happen if you make the button programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still getting this issue with iOS 5.0 (non-beta). It looks like someone created their own page curl button here:

http://blog.shuningbian.net/2011/01/ios-toolbar-pagecurl-icon.html

Alternatively you can try using this tool to extract the icon from UIKit on a version 4 device:

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: Nice one. I solved it using an own icon but this seems better. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl can only be used in toolbars, at the bottom of the screen. Else the button is simply not displayed, like in a navigation bar.